# Scala drop elements from a list

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Given the following list:

```
  sealed abstract class IntList
  case class Empty()                        extends IntList 
  case class Element(n: Int, tail: IntList) extends IntList
```

- Define the function drop(n, xs).

  - It should return the list xs, without the first n elements.

This is what I tried:

```
    def drop(n: Int, xs: IntList): IntList = xs match {
    case _ if n == 0 => xs
    case xs : Empty => Empty() 
    case xs : Element => Element(xs.tail.n, drop(n-1, xs.tail))
  }
```

but

```
error: value n is not a member of Solution.IntList
    case xs : Element => Element(xs.tail.n, drop(n-1, xs.tail))
```

I am guessing this is because xs.tail is not guaranteed to be an `Element` anymore
How should I do this? Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to construct a new list, take a look to your first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly there, but there's no need to wrap the recursive call in `Element()`

```
def drop(n: Int, xs: IntList): IntList = xs match {
  case _ if n == 0 => xs
  case xs : Empty => xs 
  case xs : Element => drop(n-1, xs.tail)
}
```

This avoids the need to call `xs.tail.n`, which you already identified as the problem!

You can also just return `xs` for the Empty case, to avoid creating a new instance. Usually one would use a `case object` for an empty case like this.